# Hugo within-page link

Tags: hugo

How do I make a within-page link with Hugo / Wowchemy? The Wowchemy [website](https://wowchemy.com/docs/content/writing-markdown-latex/) mentions that this can be done as follows:

```
[Scroll down to a page section with heading *Hi*](#hi)
```

But I tried this with a header `## Course schedule`:

```
[See Course schedule below](#Course schedule)
```

and it does not show as a link, but instead as plain text:

[See Course schedule below](#Course schedule)

With a one-word heading (`## Delivery`), the link shows properly, but if I click on that link, nothing happens, the link is lame.

```
[See the section on Delivery](#Delivery)
```

Am I missing something? Should I include an anchor? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to write:

```
[See Course schedule below](#Course-schedule)
```

You can check this by looking at the 'id' of the title.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens. The link is visible as a link now, but if I click on it, the page does not move. Also, using the associated url `http://localhost:1313/book/example/#Course-schedule` loads the page at the top.

Comment: Please right-click and inspect the source. See what `id=""` says at the title you are trying to link to. Add a `#` sign before that `id` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, using the id, this now works: `[See Course schedule below](#course-schedule)`